# React click on filtered List

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react. will really appreciate some help.
I have a list that I want to filter, and I want for each item in the list to click on it so it will open a page on the right side.

currently, the click is causing the list to disappear. I think I have an issue on the filtered list.

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            MyList: [
                'A',
                'B',
                'C'
            ],
            filter: "",
            selectedItem: ""
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleFilter = (newFilter) => {
        this.setState(() => ({
            filter: newFilter
        }));
    }

    handleClick(selectedItem) {
        this.setState((prevstate) => ({
            MyList: selectedItem
        }));
    }

    render() {

        const filteredList = this.state.MyList.filter(section =>
            section.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.filter.toLowerCase()))

        return (
            <div>
                {<Filter handleFilter={this.handleFilter} />}
                {filteredList.map((listItem, i) =>
                    <p onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}>{listItem}</p>)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


const Filter = (props) => (
    <div>
        <input name="filter" onChange={(e) => {
            props.handleFilter(e.target.value);
        }} />
    </div>
);


ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onClick function aren't you resetting your list from an initial array to a string? So on re-rendering you'll have a string as MyList. It should be:

```
handleClick(selectedItem) {
    this.setState((prevstate) => ({
      MyList: [selectedItem]
  }));
}
```